# Variable variable data not being sent into the database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to send variable variable data into a database, however, the data isn't being sent.  I'm using a jQuery $.post function to send the data, so I'm assuming that that's where the issue is, however, I'm not sure what said issue is.  Also, I understand I have SQL injection issues at this point in time.

**jQuery**

```
function verify(){
    center = $("#center_menu").val();
    initials = $("#initials").val();
    date = $("#date").val();
    recurrent = $("#recurrent_menu").val();
    name = $("#name").val();
    email = $("#email").val();
    aircraft = $("#aircraft_menu").val();
    pair1 = $("#pair1").val();
    pair2 = $("#pair2").val();
    id = scenario +center_sub +date +initials;
    center_sub = center.substring(0,4);
    scenario = pair1 +" " +pair2;
    jep_num = 0;
    $("#air_id, #chart_id, #chart_desc").children().remove();
    $(".jepp_charts").each(function(ind,item){
        jep_num = ind + 1;
        air_id = $("#air_id_" +jep_num).val();
        chart_id = $("#chart_id_" +jep_num).val();
        chart_desc = $("#chart_desc_" +jep_num).val();
        $("#air_id").append("<div id='air_id_field_" +jep_num +"' name='air_id_field_" +jep_num +"' class='table_field'><strong>Airport Identifier:  </strong>" +air_id +"</div>");
        $("#chart_id").append("<div id='chart_id_field_" +jep_num +"' name='chart_id_field_" +jep_num +"' class='table_field'><strong>Chart Identifier:  </strong>" +chart_id +"</div>");
        $("#chart_desc").append("<div id='chart_desc_field_" +jep_num +"' name='chart_desc_field_" +jep_num +"' class='table_field'><strong>Chart Description:  </strong>" +chart_desc +"</div>");
})
$("input[id='save']").on("click", function(){
    verify();
    $.post("../php/processing.php", {scenario: scenario, instructor: name, initials: initials, email: email, date: date, center: center, aircraft: aircraft, recurrent: recurrent, pair1: pair1, pair2: pair2, jepaid: air_id, jepcid: chart_id, jepdesc: chart_desc}, function(response){
        if(response.success == "1"){
        }
    }, "json");
})
```

**Php Form Processing**

```
ob_start();
require("../includes/header.php");
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    $instructor = $_SESSION["user"];
    $initials = $_POST["initials"];
    $email = $_SESSION["email"];
    $date = $_POST["date"];
    $center = $_POST["center"];
    $aircraft = $_POST["aircraft"];
    $recurrent = $_POST["recurrent"];
    $pair1 = $_POST["pair1"];
    $pair2 = $_POST["pair2"];
    $scenario = $pair1 ." " .$pair2;
    for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++){
        $jepaid = "air_id_{$i}";
        $jepcid = "chart_id_{$i}";
        $jepdesc = "chart_desc_{$i}";
        if(isset($_POST[$jepaid])){
            GLOBAL $$jepaid = $_POST[$jepaid];
            GLOBAL $$jepcid = $_POST[$jepcid];
            GLOBAL $$jepdesc = $_POST[$jepdesc];
        }
    }
    $query = "INSERT INTO `$scenarios`(`scenario`, `instructor`, `initials`, `email`, `created`, `center`, `aircraft`, `recurrent`, `city_pair1`, `city_pair2`, `air_id`, `chart_id`, `chart_desc`) VALUES('" .$scenario ."', '" .$instructor ."', '" .$initials ."', '" .$email ."', '" .$date ."', '" .$center ."', '" .$aircraft ."', '" .$recurrent ."', '" .$pair1 ."', '" .$pair2 ."', '" .$$jepaid ."', '" .$$jepcid ."', '" .$$jepdesc ."')";
    mysqli_query($connect, $query);
}
ob_clean();
echo json_encode(array("success" => 1));
```

**Database Table Creation**

```
$create_table_scenarios = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $scenarios(scenario VARCHAR(25), instructor VARCHAR(50), initials VARCHAR(3), email VARCHAR(50), created VARCHAR(25), center VARCHAR(25), aircraft VARCHAR(25), recurrent VARCHAR(50), city_pair1 VARCHAR(10), city_pair2 VARCHAR(10), air_id VARCHAR(50), chart_id VARCHAR(50), chart_desc VARCHAR(50))";
```

**HTML Form(It's not the entire form, just the problem area)**

```
<div id="form_jepp" class="form_view">
    <div id="charts">
        <h3>Jeppeson Charts</h3>
        <div class="jepp_charts">
            <fieldset>
                <label>Airport Identifier</label>
                <input type="text" class="air-id-input" name="air_id_1" id="air_id_1" />
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <label>Chart Identifier</label>
                <input type="text" class="chart-id-input" name="chart_id_1" id="chart_id_1" />
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <label>Chart Description</label>
                <input type="text" class="chart-desc-input" name="chart_desc_1" id="chart_desc_1" />
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="add">
        <label for="add_chart">Add Chart: </label>
        <button id="add_chart" name="add_chart">+</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there an error on your client side? JS console?

Comment: There's no errors, and I'm actually printing the values in the console.

Comment: echo $query, is it what you expect? check for errors `mysqli_error`

Answer (score 0):

```
Too many code for me, but any way here is some advice for you.
1. Put all your fields into form with  id="form_jepp", and your button with
 id="add_chart" make it type="submit"
2. then in jquery you have to do only simple code as follows:
```

```
$.post("../php/processing.php", $('#form_jepp').serialize(), function(response){
    if(response.success == "1"){ //blah blah
    });
```

```
3. comment all your code in 'Php Form Processing' then start by debugging the 
$_POST value simply by using
```

```
print_r($_POST);
```

4. if u see all your values then proceed with validation and data insertion.